# Counting Spaces in the console Java

Tags: java, console

With my program I need to display all happy numbers, and if the number isn't happy display a ".".
But when you display the numbers it should be in the shape of a  square. Whereas mine doesn't. Here is my code to display:

```
int space = 0;
for (int num = beginningNumber; num <= endingNumber; num++) {
    if (r1.happy(num)) {
        System.out.print(num);

        space++;

        if (space == 50) {
            System.out.println();
            space = 0;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.print(".");
        space++;
        if (space == 50) {
            System.out.println();
            space = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And my console display:

```
Enter starting number
1
Enter your ending number
1000
1.....7..10..13.....19...23....28..3132...........44....49.
.................68.70........79..82...86....91..94..97..100
..103.....109...................129130..133.....139...........
................167........176...........188.190.192193.......
..203....208..........219......226...230.....236..239...........
...........262263................280..........291.293.......
301302.......310..313.....319320.....326..329.331......338............
.....356.....362..365.367368.......376..379...383..386....391392....397...
...404....409..............................440.....446....
.............464....469........478........487..490.....496....
...................................536..............
.....556......563.565566..................................
.......608........617....622623........632..635.637638.....644....649.
..653.655656........665.....671.673......680..683..........694.....700
........709......716...................736..739........748..
..........761.763....................784.....790..793.......
.802...806...........818.820............833..836..........847...
.........860..863..........874......881......888..........899.
901..904..907..910.912913.......921.923.......931932....937..940.....946....
.............964.....970..973...............989........998.1000
```

It should look like:

```
1.....7..10..13.....19...23....28..3132...........44....49.
.................68.70........79..82...86....91..94..97.
..103.....109...................129130..133.....139.....
................167........176...........188.190.192193.
..203....208..........219......226...230.....236..239...
...........262263................280..........291.293...
301302.......310..313.....319320.....326..329.331.......
.....356.....362..365.367368.......376..379...383..386..
...404....409..............................440.....446..
.............464....469........478........487..490.....496
...................................536....................
.....556......563.565566..................................
.......608........617....622623........632..635.637638....
..653.655656........665.....671.673......680..683.........
........709......716...................736..739........748
..........761.763....................784.....790..793.....
.802...806...........818.820............833..836..........
.........860..863..........874......881......888..........
901..904..907..910.912913.......921.923.......931932....937
.............964.....970..973...............989........998.1000
```

without actually deleting the numbers like I did

Comment: So what *should* your output look like? Please [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: @GordThompson I think the output should look like the one where he says `It should look like`... wasn't clear on it though.

Comment: Doesn't my solution work ? As far as I understand you want your output to look more rectangular, which you can do by using printf

Comment: The bug in your code is that numbers take up 'n'-spaces where n is the log to base 10 + 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf("%4d",num);` instead of `System.out.print(num);` in your first loop.  `printf("%4s",".")` instead of `System.out.print(".");` in your second loop. This will align everything to have take up 4 spaces which in your case is the maximum length of your numbers. If the maximum length increases you can increase the number (at which point you probably should use `"%"+maxLength+"d"` and `"%"+maxLength+"s"`).

`d` is the converter tag for all decimal integers and `s` for strings

For further info on how printf works in java you can look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

alternatively if you want to keep your approach you need to change `space++` into something like `space = space + 1 + (int)(Math.log(num)/Math.log(10))` in your first if

But if the last (two) things in a line are numbers you can't guaranty it to end after exactly 50 characters/spaces.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is about as close as you are going to get

To producing exactly 50 character wide output.

#### [Q33114502.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q33114502.java) <- for complete working solution

```
private static int LINE_LENGTH = 50;
private static int NOT_HAPPY = -1;

public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final int start = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final int end = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    final List<Integer> happy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (isHappy(i))
        {
            happy.add(i);
        }
        else
        {
            happy.add(NOT_HAPPY);
        }
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
    final Iterator<Integer> ii = happy.iterator();
    while (ii.hasNext())
    {
        final int i = ii.next();
        if (i == NOT_HAPPY) { sb.append("."); }
        else { sb.append(String.format("%d", i)); }
        if (sb.length() >= LINE_LENGTH)
        {
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
            sb.ensureCapacity(60);
        }
        else if (!ii.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Produces the following output:

```
1.....7..10..13.....19...23....28..3132...........
44....49..................68.70........79..82...86
....91..94..97..100..103.....109..................
.129130..133.....139...........................167
........176...........188.190.192193.........203..
..208..........219......226...230.....236..239....
..................262263................280.......
...291.293.......301302.......310..313.....319320.
....326..329.331......338.................356.....
362..365.367368.......376..379...383..386....391392
....397......404....409...........................
...440.....446.................464....469........478
........487..490.....496..........................
.............536...................556......563.565
566.........................................608...
.....617....622623........632..635.637638.....644.
...649...653.655656........665.....671.673......680
..683..........694.....700........709......716....
...............736..739........748............761.
763....................784.....790..793........802
...806...........818.820............833..836......
....847............860..863..........874......881.
.....888..........899.901..904..907..910.912913...
....921.923.......931932....937..940.....946......
...........964.....970..973...............989.....
...998.1000
```